# advanced htaccess url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have developed a simple mvc in php as my final project but the system uses ugly urls. I have looked around but it seems it is very advance:
transform:

```
http://example.com/[subfolder]/controller/view/p:val/p:val/p:val
into:
http://example.com/[subfolder]/?m=controller&v=view&params[]=p:val&params[]=p:val&params[]=p:val
```

with unknown number of "p:val" and possibly subfolders.
Can someone please help me?

I have read a tutorial where one can "connect" the .htaccess file to a php file to rewrite the url. I don't know how to connect the files.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm you can map the whole request to your main php file using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /your_main_file.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you can map the request:

```
preg_match('#/(?<controller>(\w+))/(?<view>(\w+)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $result);
```

And so on...